# "Which we discussed" vs. "about which we discussed"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, verbs, prepositions

Which one is correct?

> I’ve added changes/fixes which we discussed yesterday.

or

> I’ve added changes/fixes about which we discussed yesterday.

Comment: Related: [“will discuss the matter” vs “will discuss on this matter”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2047/)

Comment: As noted in the answers, "about" is incorrect. I think the temptation to use it occurs because of the verb phrase "talk about" which means nearly the same thing as "discuss".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the *about*. However, I would probably also remove the *which* and add a *the*, making it:

> I've added the changes/fixes we discussed yesterday.

Comment: I'd phrase this stronger: it's not just that you don't *need* the "about", it's that the "about" is *incorrect*.

Answer (score 4):

"Discuss" is transitive; you discuss a thing, you never discuss about a thing.  As such, "about which we discussed" is simply incorrect.

Compare to "talk".  You talk about a thing, you never "talk a thing".  So the opposite would be true and you would have to say "the thing about which we talked", in this case.