# The use of "about" on "discuss" and "think"

Tags: adverbs

Why is it grammatically incorrect to say

> We would like to *discuss about* the matters at hands first.

But it is alright to say

> I will *think about* what you have said this morning.

What I've heard that the word *discuss* is treated like *consider* and *investigate*. It makes sense that *about* cannot be placed with *consider*, e.g. it sounds weird to say "I'll consider about this relationship."

So what are the words that will have the same effects with *discuss*, *consider* and *investigate*? What makes *look* and *think* so special that *about* is grammatically correct to be used together with them?

Comment: Related: [“Which we discussed” vs. “about which we discussed”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5289/which-we-discussed-vs-about-which-we-discussed), [“Will discuss the matter” vs. “will discuss on this matter”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/will-discuss-the-matter-or-will-discuss-on-this-matter)

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing conceptually "special" about *discuss*, *consider*, *investigate*; that's just how the words are used.

*Discuss* is always *transitive*: it requires a direct object. (However, if you *hold a discussion* it may be *about* some topic.)

*Consider* and *investigate* are usually transitive and take a direct object: you *consider* or *investigate* a topic. They may be used intransitively: "John paused to consider", or "John is going to investigate", but a direct object is always implied. (If he *conducts an investigation* it will ordinarily be *of* or *into* a topic. One does not however hold or conduct or anything-else *a consideration*— that has quite a different meaning.

*Think* may be either transitive ("Think deep thoughts") or intransitive ("John thought deeply"). If intransitive, it usually employs *about* with its topic.

There's neither a mystery nor a general principle here, just a bunch of atomic facts you have to memorize.

Answer (score 3):

The grammatical explanation is that verbs like *think* and *look* are intransitive. That means they cannot normally be followed by a direct object, but can only be complemented by a prepositional phrase which in the case of *think* usually begins with *about* (or *of*) and in the case of *look* usually begins with *at*. (An alternative interpretation sees *think about* and *look at* as prepositional verbs which are transitive and which can be followed by a direct object.)

*Discuss*, by contrast, is a transitive verb which must normally be followed by a direct object. This is supported by the figures quoted by RegDwight in his comment on GuiccoPiano's answer, and the Oxford English Dictionary has no citations at all for *discuss about*.

This, I’m afraid, doesn’t answer the question of why this should be so. That would require an investigation into the history of each word, which is not possible here.

Answer (score 0):

Google Ngrams shows a sharp rise in that phrase since 1940. It's common in Japanese-English and Chinese-English. Educated native speakers of English rarely if ever use it because they think it's incorrect usage. We **talk about something**, but we **discuss something** (without the *about*).

> - A **discussion about something** is perfectly correct.
> - "Let's **talk turkey**" is different from "Let's **talk about turkey**".
> - "Let's **discuss the matters at hand first**" is natural and idiomatic English.
> - "Let's **discuss about the matters at hand first**" is unnatural English.

Answer (score -1):

Where did you read that it is incorrect to use about with discuss?
I think discuss + about + something is correct. But when it is noun i.e. discussion then you use on. discussion + on + something.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for _discuss about_?

Comment: BNC has exactly 4 hits for "discuss about", vs. 5426 cites for simply "discuss". COCA has 11 vs. 21359. I think the situation is clear.